# Install GLIBCXX_3.4.21 locally on computer cluster

Tags: c++, gcc

I need to compile a C++ program on my machine and run it remotely on another machine. The latest GLIBCXX version I have is 3.4.21. The machine I want to run on has only up to GLIBCXX_3.4.2. So when I try to run, I get this error.

```
./test_x: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./test_x)
```

I do not have privileges on the remote machine to update to GCLIBCXX_3.4.21, so I was wondering if it's possible to install GLIBCXX_3.4.21 locally as I do not have root privileges in the cluster?

Comment: No, it is not possible, as libstdc++ is unlikely to be the only dependency. A program compiled with a newer version of gcc and libstdc++ does not have a very good chance of running with an older libstdc++. Not to mention the rest of the O/S is likely to have older libraries too, with the same issue; and even if it links, it'll likely crash for that reason. Forget the whole thing.  You're wasting your time.

Comment: Can I downgrade my version then and try to compile this way?

Comment: You'll have to downgrade not just `libstdc++`, but every other dependency as well. At this point, you're better off installing a VM with the older operating system, and built your codez on the same platform as the targeted deployment platform. That's what virtual machines are for.

Comment: @RadwaSherif: Yes, you can downgrade the g++ used to build this program and it has a good chance of working.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Can you give me some tips on how to do it without messing things up?

Comment: Just find which version of g++ came with the version of glibc++ you need, and look for a package containing that GCC (or older) for your OS.  It shouldn't be too hard for most OSes.

Comment: The first thing people usually try is to link statically (`-static`, or if that fails because of other libraries, `-static-libstdc++`).

Answer (score 0):

Note that `GLIBCXX` has *nothing* to with GLIBC -- it's a version symbol used by `libstdc++.so` and is part of GCC.

Yes: it is trivial to copy your local version of `libstdc++.so.6` to the cluster and make your program use it.

Suppose you copy your executable to `/cluster/radwa/foo`. Then copy your local `libstdc++.so.6` to `/cluster/radwa` and either  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/cluster/radwa` or link `foo` executable with `-Wl,-rpath=/cluster/radwa`.